# Google iOS DFP and Analytics for iOS not working together

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-dfp

I'm working on an iOS App where my clients requested to implemente DFP and Google Analytics.

Implementing the ad banners was easy but when I added the libraries requires by Google Analytics, xcode blew up showing 28 errors.

The errors go away when I remove the -ObjC linker flag, but this way the DPF implementation will not work.

Here are the errors, any ideas?

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSOverwriteMergePolicy", referenced from:
      +[TAGModel contextWithURL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
      +[TAGModel coordinatorWithURL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIHit.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIProperty.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TAGHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIHit.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIProperty.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl tablePresent:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl openDatabaseAndInitStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl tablePresent:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl openDatabaseAndInitStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl openDatabaseAndInitStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Anyone? Please let me know if I weren't clear enough in my explanation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try including "libsqlite3.0dylib" in your project as suggested [here](http://rusie1001.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/27/%E3%80%90%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%80%91GoogleAnalytics%E3%81%A8AdMob%E3%82%92%E4%B8%A1%E6%96%B9%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B). See if any other library or framework are missed.

Comment: Most likely, the CoreData framework is missing as well.

Comment: Awesome. I got the same error and I did have CoreData framework as directed in their docs. Not sure why they didn't specify to add this, unless there something deeper going on wrong with OP's project and mine.